# How to speed up the time it takes for UI Server to update and allow dynamic DAG to be triggered?

Tags: dynamic, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG Generator that takes a JSON input and creates a new dynamic DAG in the dags directory. The time it takes for that newly created DAG to be available to use (through the API) can range from 2 seconds to 5 minutes.

I ran the test 100 times:

1. Create a new DAG (with the same input JSON, so the dynamic dags are
   identical)
2. Once the DAG is saved in the dags directory, start
   sending API requests to see if the DAG can be triggered.
3. Track the seconds passed before I was able to successfully trigger the
   DAG.

Results are as follows:

> [14.81, 6.44, 6.38, 6.36, 2.21, 6.42, 18.96, 23.14, 23.11, 14.82, 6.39, 23.10, 18.93, 14.80, 23.20, 31.49, 48.29, 35.83, 27.20, 18.96, 14.80, 44.14, 35.66, 35.77, 39.92, 31.50, 69.15, 48.22, 69.29, 39.87, 10.53, 69.15, 27.37, 48.22, 77.51, 39.90, 27.35, 65.03, 69.16, 31.47, 65.06, 90.00, 2.19, 111.33, 69.19, 98.46, 90.16, 27.28, 60.89, 56.57, 110.96, 18.92, 140.55, 39.95, 94.22, 85.89, 44.29, 94.54, 69.21, 136.20, 35.72, 102.57, 102.63, 81.72, 98.58, 77.55, 148.83, 102.79, 136.38, 115.22, 94.38, 148.68, 119.43, 48.24, 178.09, 81.80, 127.64, 119.59, 44.22, 194.88, 23.17, 170.00, 211.47, 153.18, 249.55, 182.40, 152.98, 86.00, 157.02, 98.54, 270.02, 81.75, 153.04, 69.23, 265.92, 27.30, 278.64, 23.19, 269.98, 81.91]

Average Time: `79.35 seconds`

You can see that as the number of files in the dags folder increased, the time it took for the DAG to be triggered also increased, but it's still somewhat random. Is there any way to keep this consistent (without restarting the Airflow server after each creation). Or speed it up?

Thank you!